# simple python script to block nokia n73 screen

Tags: python, camera, pys60, n73

i want that upon opening my N73's camera cover,the camera software keeps working as usual,but that it is blocked by a black screen covering the whole screen so that it appears that the camera is not working... I know my requirement is weired but i need this.. ;)

Can anyone guide me to write a python script that does exactly this... i searched a lot over net for any existing apps but couldnot find one..

Thanks for helping..

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, Andrew...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather sceptical whether this can be achieved with PyS60. First of all, AFAIK for PyS60 program you'd need to start the interpreter environment first, autostarting when camera starts probably won't be possible.

Also, opening the camera cover probably does not have any callback so you won't be able to detect it from python however, you could try something like this presented in PyS60 1.4.5 doc (http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/pys60/pys60/1.4.5/PythonForS60_1_4_5_doc.pdf):

```
>>> import appuifw
>>> import camera
>>> def cb(im):
... appuifw.app.body.blit(im)
...
>>> import graphics
>>> appuifw.app.body=appuifw.Canvas()
>>> camera.start_finder(cb)
```

Instead of blitting im you could just blit a black screen and store im. Or something. But seriously, this sounds like some very bad prank...